# How to insert into SQL Server Compact

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I am working with .NET 4.5 and C# using a SQL Server Compact database.

[image]

Here is the insert command I am using:

```
try
{
    conn.Open();
    String query = "INSERT INTO categories (cat_title) VALUES (@cat_title)";

    SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(query, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cat_title", cat_title);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
```

After I do this, I immediately get results from the table to populate a combobox. I can see the newly added item.

However, when I go back to the Database Explorer, the items are not there. If I run the app again, I can see the item or items I added.

If I refresh the dB from the Database Explorer, the results are not longer present in the app.

Am I doing this right? Why would the results behave this way?

Comment: YEs. It is a Windows Form Application.

Comment: "If I run the app again, I can see the item or items I added." This almost certainly means that your DB explorer is pointing to a different DB :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - or when he "refreshes the dB" he erases the values which were saved.  Maybe the explorer is auto-clearing the tables.

Comment: Yes, that is what it sounded like to me. However, if I refresh the dB in the DB Explorer, my app shows the results that are present in that dB.

Comment: I've add an image of the table in question. I've gone back and re-created the dB and it is working fine now. So I'm still lost as to what went wrong.

Comment: Does this happen when you run the app from Visual Studio? If so: can you please show us the **connection string** you're using? Quite possibly, Visual Studio is copying around the `.sdf` file and you're inserting your data into a copy in your app's runtime directory, which is discarded at the end of the run....

Comment: What @marc_s said, I find that whatever's in the `App_Data` folder has `Copy to Output Directory` set to true (or whatever it's called). Each build it gets copied again.

Answer (score 0):

@marc_s and @ta.speot.is are correct, but for the other newbies out there I think I might also chime in.

The database that you see in the explorer is reading a different instance of the .sdf file than the one your connection string is referencing. It is possible that the explorer is reading the .sdf file from your main project directory, while your connection string is connecting to the .sdf file in you bin/debug/ folder. If this is the case, the .sdf file that your connection string references will be overwritten every time the program runs.